# Jquery Autocomplete with ASP.NET Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using JqueryUI autocomplete widget with asp.net 
i create one class file that contain method that will return list of search result.
and on aspx page i called all required jquery file.
on Script part i write below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "CommonOperation.cs/GetClientName",
                    data: "{'SearchVal':'" + document.getElementById('<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error......");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

don't know what problem is their but when i run it always goes in Error part.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: No error getting just display alert box with contain text "Error......"

Comment: Instead of alerting "Error......", why not alert the actual error? Also, press F12, go to Network, run your autocomplete, and you should see the problematic call highlighted in red. Clicking on it will tell you the request and the response.

Comment: how to display this error

Comment: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}`

Comment: Is the url correct? `url: CommonOperation.cs/GetClientName,`

Comment: Url seems awfully strange.

Comment: error not found display in console log

Comment: So any one can tell me how to use class file method in this???

Comment: @WeeZy does the below answer fix your issue ?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy No it will not work

Comment: Think about it, is a .cs file something that is exposed as a "URL" ? No? Modify your code structure accordingly and call a web method.

Comment: Are you using `GetClientName` as `WebMethod` in server side?

Comment: @WeeZy you are doing it wrong. You must call a web method and not any random method in .cs file. Here is what you can do to debug this. First open the developer tools in your browser press F12 for this. Now with this tools window open reload your page. Now choose the `Network` tab in it  and try the auto complete action. Now you should see all the requests that are sent to server. click on this request and it will give you complete details of the request, response etc etc.. You can choose the `preview` tab for seeing the regular asp.net yellow screen error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put your web method in a class file, as the method itself needs to be web-accessible.

Move it to a standard ASPX page's code-behind, and use the `.aspx` link instead of `.cs`.

---

An alternative would simply be to use an `.asmx`, and attach your class to that instead. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363743/2026606) provides some information on that:

> You could use something like an asmx (ASP.Net web service) that exposes the webmethods. The file is basically just a markup place holder that points at a class file. Contents are just:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/foo/MyClass.cs" Class="MyClass" %>
```

> Then your class has to inherit from `System.Web.Services.WebService` and you should be good.
>
> If you do an add file from Visual Studio and add a web service file you can get it to create all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

here url should be like this-> url:"CommonOperation.aspx/GetClientName",

Comment: but this is class file that i created for such common operation

Answer (score -1):

Done It
Method will be static and declared as WebMethod and Call it from aspx.cs

Comment: Rather than posting your own answer to confirm that someone else's worked, you should just instead accept the original correct answer.